# Magento 2.1: Get ID of saved category

Tags: magento2, category, event-observer, magento-2.1.3, plugin

Because in Magento 2.1.3 the category_after_save event is missing I created a afterExecute plugin for the category save plugin. If I save a existing category the request contains the entity_id, but if I create a new one the entity_id does not exist in the post parameters. Is there an other way to get this id?

Comment: You can easily get category id using url:
First create category and open that category and see at the url or address bar of the browser.
Here at the last of url you can see .../id/4

Comment: I need to get the category id in my plugin not in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from extracting directly from the response object, there doesn't appear to be a publicly accessible point in the category save controller to get the **entity_id** for new instances.

The good news is, you can still utilize the *after_save* method in Magento 2.1.3. Since it extends **Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel**, events are generated using

```
public function afterSave()
{
    ...
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
    ...
}
```

To utilize it, you'll just need to create an events file
`<module_directory>/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
        <observer name="example_module_catalog_category_save_after" instance="Example\Module\Observer\Catalog\CategorySaveAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

And a corresponding Observer `<module_directory>/Observer/Catalog/CategorySaveObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace Example\Module\Observer\Catalog;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CategorySaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
    }
}
```

This will give you access to the category data, regardless if it's new or existing.